# IIS Dynamic IP Address Restriction to permanently block IP

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, ip-address, windows-server-2008-r2

So I have a website that is getting hit regularly from someone scraping our content and I would like to do my best to annoy him as possible.

Currently we have IIS Dynamic IP address restriction on but this only temp blocks him for a very short time. Is it possible to have the same sort of rules but permanently block him instead.

So if we have 20 requests in 10 seconds from the same IP address that IP address is then block indefinitely (or a preset time I can pick)

we currently using IIS7.5

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you should look at [this](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions), it is an extension for IIS . You can actually set it up in such a way that if a user reaches a certain number of connections they are getting denied.

Hope this helps !

Comment: that only provides a temporary block e.g. if they hit 5 requests in 10 seconds then block them until they no longer have 5 requests in last 10 seconds.